# Subtracting two columns of decimals in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

aI have a dataframe which contains two columns of decimals and i would like to subtract one column from the other one. However, when i try to do something like this:

```
df['diff'] = df['a'] - ['b']
```

i get

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

I import the csv like so:

```
pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t',
                   parse_dates = ['datetime'],
                   dtype={'a': decimal.Decimal, 'b': decimal.Decimal})
```

Sample of data:

```
datetime    a   b
2014-10-15T00:00:01.752Z    8614.0  8616.0
2014-10-15T00:00:02.049Z    8613.0  8616.0
2014-10-15T00:00:02.049Z    8613.0  8616.0
2014-10-15T00:00:02.159Z    8613.0  8616.0
2014-10-15T00:00:02.159Z    8613.0  8616.0
2014-10-15T00:00:02.299Z    8614.0  8616.0
2014-10-15T00:00:02.299Z    8614.0  8616.0
2014-10-15T00:00:02.440Z    8614.0  8616.0
2014-10-15T00:00:02.440Z    8614.0  8616.0
```

Comment: Why not just set them to floats and then do a diff? Do you need them to be decimal? Can you post your raw data, the csv parser should be able to sniff the dtype if it's stored like so: `19.2222` but if any values on that column are different then it may have mixed dtypes or if it's stored as a string like `'19.2222'` then you need to convert them

Comment: i am concerned about precisionwhen working with doubles

Comment: You mean 64bit floats are not good enough precision?

Comment: no i mean the weird rounding errors you get when working with doubles

Comment: Currently I don't see the issue, you have no decimal values here anyway and by default if you didn't specify the dtype in `read_csv` then it defaults to `np.float64`

Comment: but i did specify dtype in the read_csv, or am i missing something? Is there some other way to specify dtype?

Comment: You did but it looks like it's stored as an `np.Object` but this may not be compatible with numpy arrays so it's converted it to a `str` I get `str` as the type, try `print(type(df.iloc[0]['a'])` and you will see that in fact it is a str

Answer (score 0):

Just use np.float64 instead of decimal.Decimal